# AutoFixture Customize vs Build

Tags: c#, autofixture

I know I can use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) to create an auto-mocked instance using

```cs
var person = fixture.Create<Person>();
```

But, if I want to customise the way a `Person` is created I have several options. One is to use `Build`

```cs
var person = fixture.Build<Person>()
                    .With(x => x.FirstName, "Owain")
                    .Create();
```

And another is to use `Customize`

```cs
fixture.Customize<Person>(c => c.With(x => x.FirstName, "Owain"));
var person = fixture.Create<Person>();
```

So, my question is, what are the various merits and pitfalls of each approach listed above, and are there any other / better approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Build<>.With().Create()` creates the instance with those properties. Future calls to `.Create<>()` (for the same type) are unnafected.

`.Customize<>` defines extra "steps" for the creation of a type. This means that all future calls to `.Create<>()` (for the same type) will go through the same steps.

Basically, you would use customize for cases where all created objects of a specific type require the same set-up.

---

```
var person_1 = fixture.Build<Person>()
    .With(x => x.FirstName, "Owain")
    .Create();

var person_2 = fixture.Create<Person>();

fixture.Customize<Person>(c => c.With(x => x.FirstName, "Owain"));
// All subsequent calls to Create for type Person will use the customization.

var person_3 = fixture.Create<Person>();
var person_4 = fixture.Create<Person>();

//person_1.FirstName == "Owain"
//person_2.FirstName != "Owain"
//person_3.FirstName == "Owain"
//person_4.FirstName == "Owain"
```

---

Relevant pages of the holy book:

1. Customize: [Customizing A Type's Builder With AutoFixture](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/09/22/CustomizingAType'sBuilderWithAutoFixture/)
2. Build.Do.With: [Do Redux](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/08/25/DoRedux/)